# Word to describe realization of one's power or potency

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English that could robustly and vividly describe the realization of one's power or potency? For example, something that you might feel after, like in good old fairy tales, the wizard says "the strength was within you all this time"?

I almost sure I encountered the word that fits the description.

Comment: perhaps _epiphany_

Comment: "achievement" or "achieving" is a word commonly associated with "realization" of potential ... although it's focus is perhaps more on the successful effort than the result.

Comment: You can say that someone *has come into his or her own*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is ***self-discovery*** which is about realizing one's true character (and not limited to one's *power or potency* alone).

ODO:

> **[self-discovery](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-discovery)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> The process of acquiring insight into one's own character.
>
> ‘The result is a sublime and surreal saga of self-discovery and
>   personal growth, of existential doubt and doubtful existences.’

Comment: Hey, nice answer! That is very close to what I'm looking for! I think I'm gonna wait a bit in case the word I heard some time ago would come up, and if not, I'll accept your answer. Thank you again!

Comment: @DmitryVolkov, happy to help. I wish you find what you are looking for, though.

Answer (score 1):

[Potential](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/potential).
Someone’s potential is an ability the person has not yet developed. "You too can achieve your ultimate potential."

Another form is [potentiality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiality_and_actuality), which alludes somewhat to the idea that it manifests as a fundamental force of nature.

Actualization or [Self-Actualization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-actualization), a term from existential psychology, the coming into one's own fulfillment.

Comment: Hey, John Wu. Thanks for an answer! Though I'm not sure that really fits the description. You see, potential is another word to describe what person discovers in him-/herself, but the goal of my search is the word that describes the fact of understanding of the potential, the awareness of potency. The key word is "realization", I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Attraction** from the "Law of attraction"
The belief is based on the idea that people and their thoughts are both made from "pure energy", and that through the process of "like energy attracting like energy" a person can improve their own health, wealth and personal relationships.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_attraction_(New_Thought)

Comment: Hello, Baiwir, thank you for your answer! That's a nice article you brought, I'm kinda curious about the philosophy of New Thought. But I think that word cannot be used to describe realization or revelation about oneself; that's rather the mechanism of change, I presume.